# imshow of opencv on mac os does not displays pixel intensity value and the coordinate points?

Tags: macos, opencv, coordinates, display, imshow

I am working on mac and using python 2.7 and opencv. I am not able to see the X and Y coordinates of pixels on the gui after using cv2.imshow() when moving the mouse on the gui after image display. Please help I need to use this feature for debugging .

Comment: OpenCV is not a GUI Framework. `cv::imshow` has the purpose of debugging RGB images and lacks any other advanced functionalities. However you can implement it using the `mouse_callback` API.

Comment: You may want to use OpenCV [`ccv`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html) module

Comment: Without the cvv module, I think the pixel values in opencv gui show up with the QT-based GUI : https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html